# NoClassDefFoundError in OSGi although it is exported and imported

Tags: java, maven, osgi, virtual-reality, apache-karaf

I tried to create a basic virtual reality IDE based on Karaf.

I have 3 maven-projects:

1. VRServer who connect to a native-component for rendering.
2. VR Component Toolkit for VR-HMI-Widgets (Having a VRFrame who extends from VRComponent) as a Multi-Module-Maven-Project.
3. The VR IDE project read/write files and execute lowlevel commands.

[image]

I installed all of them into Karaf:

```
karaf@root()> bundle:list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
 ID | State  | Lvl | Version            | Name
----+--------+-----+--------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 31 | Active |  80 | 4.3.0              | Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
 54 | Active |  80 | 1.3.2              | Apache Aries SPI Fly Dynamic Weaving Bundle
 55 | Active |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm
 56 | Active |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.commons
 57 | Active |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.tree
 58 | Active |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis
 59 | Active |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.util
 60 | Active |  80 | 2.0.17             | OpenWebBeans Core
 61 | Active |  80 | 2.0.17             | SPI definition
 62 | Active |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - CDI Component Runtime (CCR)
 63 | Active |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - SPI classes for Portable Extensions
 64 | Active |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - Container using Apache OpenWebBeans
 65 | Active |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - SPI
 66 | Active |  80 | 1.0.12             | Apache Felix Converter
 67 | Active |  80 | 1.2.0              | Apache Geronimo JSR-330 Spec 1.0
 68 | Active |  80 | 1.1.0              | Apache Geronimo Expression Language Spec 2.2
 69 | Active |  80 | 1.2.0              | Apache Geronimo Interceptor Spec 1.2
 70 | Active |  80 | 1.2.0              | Apache Geronimo JCDI Spec 2.0
 71 | Active |  80 | 1.3.0.3            | Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Annotation API 1.3
 72 | Active |  80 | 4.17.0             | Apache XBean :: ASM shaded (repackaged)
 73 | Active |  80 | 4.17.0             | Apache XBean OSGI Bundle Utilities
 74 | Active |  80 | 4.17.0             | Apache XBean :: Finder shaded (repackaged)
 75 | Active |  80 | 1.0.1.201505202024 | org.osgi:org.osgi.namespace.extender
 76 | Active |  80 | 1.0.0.201505202024 | org.osgi:org.osgi.namespace.implementation
 77 | Active |  80 | 1.0.0.201505202024 | org.osgi:org.osgi.namespace.service
 78 | Active |  80 | 1.0.0.201810101357 | org.osgi:org.osgi.service.cdi
 79 | Active |  80 | 1.1.0.201802012106 | org.osgi:org.osgi.util.function
 80 | Active |  80 | 1.1.0.201802012106 | org.osgi:org.osgi.util.promise
 81 | Active |  80 | 4.3.1.SNAPSHOT     | Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
134 | Active |  80 | 1.0.0              | Virtual reality server
135 | Active |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | VRComponent
136 | Active |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | VRFrame
142 | Active |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | Virtual reality integrated development environment (VRIDE)
karaf@root()>
```

But when I tried to start the VRIDE bundle, I get this exception:

```
10:00:42.193 WARN [fileinstall-C:\Program Files\apache-karaf-4.3.0/deploy] Error while creating extension
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lde/e_nexus/vr/tk/VRFrame;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2611) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1944) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.util.Reflection.allFields(Reflection.java:47) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.annotated.AnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeImpl.java:42) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.container.Discovery.lambda$discover$8(Discovery.java:133) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:981) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
```

This is the Java-Class I tried to load:

```
package de.e_nexus.desktop.vr.ide;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.osgi.service.cdi.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.cdi.annotations.Service;

import de.e_nexus.vr.server.ClientKeyboardScancode;
import de.e_nexus.vr.server.VRClientHelmetAndControllerListener;
import de.e_nexus.vr.server.VRClientKeyboardListener;
import de.e_nexus.vr.server.VRServer;
import de.e_nexus.vr.server.listeners.VRClientRequestAppInfo;
import de.e_nexus.vr.server.listeners.VRClientStatusListener;
import de.e_nexus.vr.server.listeners.interaction.HelmetAndControllerInfo;
import de.e_nexus.vr.server.osgi.inter.VRServerService;
import de.e_nexus.vr.tk.VRFrame;

@ApplicationScoped
@Service
public class StartIDE implements VRClientStatusListener, VRClientRequestAppInfo, VRClientHelmetAndControllerListener, VRClientKeyboardListener {
    /**
     * The logger for this class.
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StartIDE.class.getCanonicalName());

    private final static Object lock = new Object();

    private VRServer vrServer;

    public void notifyStatus(boolean connected) {
        if (!connected) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                lock.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Reference
    @Inject
    private VRServerService vrServerService;

    private VRFrame applicationFrame;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
        LOG.fine("Starting VR IDE");
        vrServer = vrServerService.getVRServer();
        applicationFrame = new VRFrame(vrServer, "test");

        LOG.info(getLatin1Title() + " started successfully!");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void teardown() {
        applicationFrame.remove();
        LOG.info("Stoped " + getLatin1Title() + " successfully!");
        vrServer = null;
    }

    public VRServer getVrServer() {
        return vrServer;
    }

    @Override
    public void notify(HelmetAndControllerInfo haci) {

    }

    @Override
    public String getLatin1Title() {
        return "VR IDE";
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyKeyboardEvent(ClientKeyboardScancode[] downs, ClientKeyboardScancode[] ups, long incomingTime) {
        System.out.println("me");
    }
}
```

[VRServer-Codebase](https://github.com/enexusde/VRServer)

[VRToolkit-Codebase](https://github.com/enexusde/VRAbstractComponentToolkit)

[VRIDE-Codebase](https://github.com/enexusde/Virtual-Reality-Integrated-Development-Environment-VRIDE-)

---

## EDIT:

Here is the complete stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lde/e_nexus/vr/tk/VRFrame;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2611) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1944) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.util.Reflection.allFields(Reflection.java:47) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.annotated.AnnotatedTypeImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeImpl.java:42) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.container.Discovery.lambda$discover$8(Discovery.java:133) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:981) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.container.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:130) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.container.ContainerState.<init>(ContainerState.java:178) ~[!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.aries.cdi.container.internal.Activator.doCreateExtension(Activator.java:209) [!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:242) [!/:1.1.3]
        at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:227) [!/:1.1.3]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:488) [osgi.core-7.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:420) [osgi.core-7.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232) [osgi.core-7.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450) [osgi.core-7.0.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:915) [org.apache.felix.framework-6.0.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:834) [org.apache.felix.framework-6.0.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:516) [org.apache.felix.framework-6.0.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4817) [org.apache.felix.framework-6.0.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2336) [org.apache.felix.framework-6.0.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998) [org.apache.felix.framework-6.0.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1260) [!/:3.6.8]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1233) [!/:3.6.8]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:520) [!/:3.6.8]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:365) [!/:3.6.8]
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:316) [!/:3.6.8]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.e_nexus.vr.tk.VRFrame not found by de.e-nexus.component [87]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1597) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1375) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1618) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1548) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$300(BundleWiringImpl.java:79) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1982) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_232]
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: I tried in my linux https://gist.github.com/ozkanpakdil/20b2b92d03f8ec323cb6b3980293b75b looks like working, did you try to put kraf to another folder like c:/tools/ ?

Comment: @özkanpakdil Thank you for your effort. You successfully loaded the OSGi bundles, unfortunately they are OSGi-CDI bundles. So you need a CDI container in OSGi. Please install a CDI container by the commands in the comment of this tutorial-video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFgXPs251po&t=701s  first.

Comment: @Grim where do you export the package of your VFrame class? Shouldn't there be an additional Export-Package instruction within the pom file?

Comment: @rmunge By default https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#export-package exports all packages. You can proove that by building the VRComponentToolkit using `mvn` and inspect the resulting `frame-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. You will notice that the `MANIFEST.MF` contains your `Export-Package: de.e_nexus.vr.tk.abs;version="0.0.1";uses:="de.e_nexus
 .vr.server,de.e_nexus.vr.server.mesh,de.e_nexus.vr.tk,(...)`.

Comment: @Grim can you tell how to test StartIDE , is it karaf command ? or how are you planning to call it in karaf console ? I manage to deploy these without error, they look like started, I see some log in the console, but I could not find a way to test startIde :) Karaf newbie here

Comment: @özkanpakdil We can do that in a separate [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226961/karaf-osgi-vr) if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Logging points-out:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.e_nexus.vr.tk.VRFrame not found by de.e-nexus.component [87]
```

What means Karaf is searching the VRFrame from the component submodule, which clearly does not exist.

That makes sense since all java packages are exported, the VRFrame's package is ambiguous. I followed what özkan pakdil said and renamed the java-packages to a unique name. Since that it works like a charm.

Thanks Özkan! Your answer includes some usefull hints and the source of my problem was the ambiguous package-name.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in the project is `<extensions>true</extensions>` in maven-bundle-plugin. You need to have it in your pom.xml. example code

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Bundle-Activator>${Bundle-Activator}</Bundle-Activator>
            <Export-Package>
                de.*;version=${project.version}
            </Export-Package>
            <Import-Package>
                *
            </Import-Package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And packaging should be bundle like `<packaging>bundle</packaging>` for the OSGI bundles. You can see how package created from this command

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-bundle-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=4.3.0 \
    -DgroupId=io.github.ozkanpakdil \
    -DartifactId=myfirstbundle \
    -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT \
    -Dpackage=io.github.ozkanpakdil
```

https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_creating_bundles is explaining nicely. Other then that I highly suggest have namespaces without underscore. Instead of "e_nexus" have enexus and for `<groupId>de.e-nexus</groupId>` have `<groupId>de.enexus</groupId>`. Last but not least instead of `<artifactId>vr.server</artifactId>` have `<artifactId>vrserver</artifactId>`, I am suggesting these because OSGI is already complicated enviroenment, having simple and easy names will make easier to catch errors and maintain the code. Also it will prevent problems in case you move to another OS, you never know how these behaves between OSes.

**There were some warnings related to same namespace is in different jars**, I changed the code in "frame" and "component" modules accordingly. Below is the log from local, I can see that VR-Client log, I think it started working as expected.

```
ozkan@DESKTOP-NF90OD6 MINGW64 /c/Program Files/apache-karaf-4.3.0/bin
$ ./karaf
        __ __                  ____
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/

  Apache Karaf (4.3.0)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

Start Osgi spiced VR Server ... [OK]  @10:23 (You might get asked by the firewall if you like to allow java to communicate to other systems. In order to connect the local VR-Client you are requested to grant the communication.)
karaf@root()> bundle:list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
ID | State    | Lvl | Version            | Name
---+----------+-----+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
31 | Active   |  80 | 4.3.0              | Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
55 | Active   |  80 | 1.0.0              | Virtual reality server
56 | Active   |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | VRComponent
57 | Active   |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | VRFrame
58 | Active   |  80 | 1.3.2              | Apache Aries SPI Fly Dynamic Weaving Bundle
59 | Active   |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm
60 | Active   |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.commons
61 | Active   |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.tree
62 | Active   |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis
63 | Active   |  80 | 9.0.0              | org.objectweb.asm.util
64 | Active   |  80 | 2.0.17             | OpenWebBeans Core
65 | Active   |  80 | 2.0.17             | SPI definition
66 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - CDI Component Runtime (CCR)
67 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - SPI classes for Portable Extensions
68 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - Container using Apache OpenWebBeans
69 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.3              | Apache Aries CDI - SPI
70 | Active   |  80 | 1.0.12             | Apache Felix Converter
71 | Active   |  80 | 1.2.0              | Apache Geronimo JSR-330 Spec 1.0
72 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.0              | Apache Geronimo Expression Language Spec 2.2
73 | Active   |  80 | 1.2.0              | Apache Geronimo Interceptor Spec 1.2
74 | Active   |  80 | 1.2.0              | Apache Geronimo JCDI Spec 2.0
75 | Active   |  80 | 1.3.0.3            | Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Annotation API 1.3
76 | Active   |  80 | 4.17.0             | Apache XBean :: ASM shaded (repackaged)
77 | Active   |  80 | 4.17.0             | Apache XBean OSGI Bundle Utilities
78 | Active   |  80 | 4.17.0             | Apache XBean :: Finder shaded (repackaged)
79 | Active   |  80 | 1.0.1.201505202024 | org.osgi:org.osgi.namespace.extender
80 | Active   |  80 | 1.0.0.201505202024 | org.osgi:org.osgi.namespace.implementation
81 | Active   |  80 | 1.0.0.201505202024 | org.osgi:org.osgi.namespace.service
82 | Active   |  80 | 1.0.0.201810101357 | org.osgi:org.osgi.service.cdi
83 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.0.201802012106 | org.osgi:org.osgi.util.function
84 | Active   |  80 | 1.1.0.201802012106 | org.osgi:org.osgi.util.promise
85 | Resolved |  80 | 4.3.1.SNAPSHOT     | Apache Karaf :: OSGi Services :: Event
86 | Active   |  80 | 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT     | Virtual reality integrated development environment (VRIDE)
karaf@root()> log:display
10:23:10.508 INFO [activator-1-thread-2] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.log.core/4.3.0
10:23:10.821 INFO [activator-1-thread-2] Deployment finished. Registering FeatureDeploymentListener
10:23:10.821 INFO [activator-1-thread-2] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.features.command/4.3.0
10:23:10.828 INFO [activator-1-thread-3] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.kar.core/4.3.0
10:23:10.855 INFO [FelixStartLevel] Command registration delayed for bundle org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh/4.3.0. Missing service: [org.apache.sshd.server.SshServer]
10:23:10.871 INFO [FelixStartLevel] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.system.core/4.3.0
10:23:10.893 INFO [FelixStartLevel] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.event/4.3.0
10:23:11.089 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering commands for bundle org.apache.karaf.shell.ssh/4.3.0
10:23:11.128 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] No detected/configured IoServiceFactoryFactory using Nio2ServiceFactoryFactory
10:23:12.346 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.PackageStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=packageState,version=1.5,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.346 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.wiring.BundleWiringStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=wiringState,version=1.1,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.346 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.BundleStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=bundleState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.351 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.ServiceStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=serviceState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.352 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.FrameworkMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=framework,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.353 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.service.cm.ConfigurationAdminMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.compendium:service=cm,version=1.3,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.388 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Unregistering org.osgi.jmx.framework.PackageStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=packageState,version=1.5,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.389 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Unregistering org.osgi.jmx.framework.wiring.BundleWiringStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=wiringState,version=1.1,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.390 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Unregistering org.osgi.jmx.framework.BundleStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=bundleState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.390 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Unregistering org.osgi.jmx.framework.ServiceStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=serviceState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.391 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Unregistering org.osgi.jmx.framework.FrameworkMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.core:type=framework,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.392 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Unregistering org.osgi.jmx.service.cm.ConfigurationAdminMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@a766065 with name osgi.compendium:service=cm,version=1.3,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.394 WARN [activator-1-thread-1] Task rejected for JMX Notification dispatch of event [org.osgi.framework.ServiceEvent[source=[javax.management.MBeanServer]]] - Dispatcher may have been shutdown
10:23:12.420 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.PackageStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@4a85005 with name osgi.core:type=packageState,version=1.5,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.421 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.wiring.BundleWiringStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@4a85005 with name osgi.core:type=wiringState,version=1.1,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.422 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.BundleStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@4a85005 with name osgi.core:type=bundleState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.423 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.ServiceStateMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@4a85005 with name osgi.core:type=serviceState,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.423 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.framework.FrameworkMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@4a85005 with name osgi.core:type=framework,version=1.7,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
10:23:12.424 INFO [activator-1-thread-1] Registering org.osgi.jmx.service.cm.ConfigurationAdminMBean to MBeanServer org.apache.karaf.management.internal.EventAdminMBeanServerWrapper@4a85005 with name osgi.compendium:service=cm,version=1.3,framework=org.apache.felix.framework,uuid=1ba06c85-21b1-4145-9726-b08a81b6cad3
```

Comment: Thank you again for your effort. I can not use enexus.de since it is a different organizaion.